# How to organise JSON Structs in an array

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have used JSON structs before and managed to get them working with a different API, but this API's JSON data is slightly different, it seems to encompass the data in an array called 'List'. I assume it is the Structs below that are in the incorrect format? As when I run the app, I don't get any error messages, but the Label value that I am trying to change, does not change, nor does the value of 'Test' get printed to the console. I am trying to call the Description value and print it to a label.

JSON Structs below:

```
struct MyForecast : Decodable {
    let cod : String
    let message : Double
    let cnt : Int
    let list : [List]
    let city : Cityy
    let coordinate : Coordi
}

struct Coordi : Decodable {
    let lat, lon : Double
}

struct Cityy : Decodable {
    let id, population : Int
    let name, country : String
    let coord : Coordinate
}

struct Mainn : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax : Double
    let seaLevel, grndLevel, tempKf: Double
    let pressure, humidity : Int
}

struct Windd : Decodable {
    let speed : Double
    let deg : Double
}

struct Weatherr : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let icon : String
    let main : MainEnum
    let description: String
}

struct List : Decodable {
    let dt : Date
    let main : MainForecast
    let weather : [Weatherr]
    let clouds : Cloudss
    let wind : Windd
    let sys : Syss
    let dtTxt : String
    let rain: Rainn?
    let city: Cityy
}

struct Syss : Decodable {
    let pod: Pod
}

struct MainForecast : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax, pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity, tempKf : Double?
}

struct Cloudss : Decodable {
    let all : Int
}

struct Rainn: Codable {
    let the3H: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the3H = "3h"
    }
}

enum Pod: String, Codable {
    case d = "d"
    case n = "n"
}

enum MainEnum: String, Codable {
    case clear = "Clear"
    case clouds = "Clouds"
    case rain = "Rain"
}
```

ViewController below:

```
class ForecastViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        guard let APIUrl = URL (string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&APPID=***APIKEY***&units=metric") else { return }
        //API KEY


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        let decoderr = JSONDecoder()

        do {

            decoderr.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            decoderr.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970

        let forecastData = try decoderr.decode(MyForecast.self, from: data)

        if let test = forecastData.list.first?.city.name { //using .first because Weather is stored in an array
            let description = test.description
            print(description)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.testLabel.text! = description
            }
        }

            else
                {
                    print("weather not found")
                }

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: You are debuting. So each time you are doing a `if` or a `if let`, please add an `else { print("something")}` to know that you didn't pass that test when it's not working. Or simply use Breakpoints. It could be because `test` is `nil`, because `foreCastData.weather` is nil ? Because `forecastData.weather?.first` is nil?  Etc. You shouldn't need the `if (self.testLabel != nil)` because you have `var testLabel: UILabel!`.

Comment: Since this is your first question, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In this case, vital information would be an example of the data you're expected to parse.

Answer (score 1):

**Your structs <strike>are</strike> were wrong** before you edited the question.

The 5 day / 3 hour Forecast API of `openweathermap.org` sends a different JSON structure as the Current Weather Data.

You can create the structs very easy yourself:

- Download the `Data`
- Create a (JSON) string from the data
- Copy the text
- Open [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift)
- Paste the text in the JSON text field on the left side
- Add a suitable name for the root object.

quicktype.io creates the structs for you.

The forecast structs are (except `Rain` **there are no optionals at all**)

```
struct MyForecast : Decodable {
    let cod : String
    let message : Double
    let cnt : Int
    let list : [List]
    let city : City
}

struct Coordinate : Decodable {
    let lat, lon : Double
}

struct City : Decodable {
    let id, population : Int
    let name, country : String
    let coord : Coordinate
}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax : Double
    let seaLevel, grndLevel, tempKf: Double
    let pressure, humidity : Int
}

struct Wind : Decodable {
    let speed : Double
    let deg : Double
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let icon : String
    let main : MainEnum
    let description: String
}

struct List : Decodable {
    let dt : Date
    let main : MainForecast
    let weather : [Weather]
    let clouds : Clouds
    let wind : Wind
    let sys : Sys
    let dtTxt : String
    let rain: Rain?
}

struct Sys : Decodable {
    let pod: Pod
}

struct MainForecast : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax, pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity, tempKf : Double
}

struct Clouds : Decodable {
    let all : Int
}

struct Rain: Codable {
    let the3H: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the3H = "3h"
    }
}

enum Pod: String, Codable {
    case d, n
}

enum MainEnum: String, Codable {
    case clear = "Clear"
    case clouds = "Clouds"
    case rain = "Rain"
}
```

To decode the structs you have to add date and key decoding strategies.

`List` and `Weather` are arrays

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
let forecastData = try decoder.decode(MyForecast.self, from: data)
if let test = forecastData.list.first?.weather.first? { //using .first because Weather is stored in an array
    let description = test.description
    print(description)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.testLabel.text! = description
    }
} else { print("weather not found") }
```

Comment: I have implemented these Structs, (I have changed a few Struct names as they conflict with other struct names from a different class),  and I have implemented the code you suggested for my main controller, I do not get any errors and the code builds fine.  But the label Value still does not change, and I get the error 'The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.' displayed in the console.  Code above updated.

Comment: But this is the same problem with your question as before. It is not about JSON or structs at all! You need to rewrite completely so that the question is about the problem you are actually having, namely the issue with the label.

Comment: Your naming with the double consonants is a mess. If you want to use both Current Weather and Forecast API declare the corresponding struct sets separately inside other (different) structs. And your updated code cannot work because `List` doesn't have a `city` property and `city.name` doesn't have a description property. **Read** the structs and try to understand the correlation between each other.